# How do I get the actual ip address of the visitor instead of his public ip address?

Tags: c#, asp.net, http, c#-4.0, network-programming

I am using this code to get the actual ip address of the visitor my website but it returns the PUBLIC ip address which is same for everybody in our office but instead I want the actual ipv4 address of the visitor's system.

```
    protected string GetIPAddress()
    {
        System.Web.HttpContext context = System.Web.HttpContext.Current;
        string ipAddress = context.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];




        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ipAddress))
        {
            string[] addresses = ipAddress.Split(',');
            if (addresses.Length != 0)
            {
                return addresses[0];
            }
        }

        return context.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
    }

    protected string GetIPAddressLocal()
    {
        System.Web.HttpContext context = System.Web.HttpContext.Current;
        string ipAddress = context.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ipAddress))
        {
            string[] addresses = ipAddress.Split(',');
            if (addresses.Length != 0)
            {
                return addresses[addresses.Length-1];
            }
        }

        return context.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
    }

    public static IPAddress GetIPAddress3(string hostName)
    {
        Ping ping = new Ping();
        var replay = ping.Send(hostName);

        if (replay.Status == IPStatus.Success)
        {
            return replay.Address;
        }
        return null;
    }

    private string GetIP()
    {
        string strHostName = "";
        strHostName = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName();

        IPHostEntry ipEntry = System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(strHostName);

        string ipaddress = "";

        return ipaddress.ToString();

    }

    public static string GetUserIP()
    {
        var ip = (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"] != null
        && System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"] != "")
        ? System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"]
        : System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
        if (ip.Contains(","))
            ip = ip.Split(',').First().Trim();
        return ip;
    }






string ipaddress = GetIPAddress();
            ViewBag.ip = ipaddress;
            ViewBag.ip2= System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(System.Net.Dns.GetHostName()).AddressList.GetValue(1).ToString();
            ViewBag.ip3 = Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
            ViewBag.ip4 = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress;
            ViewBag.ip5 = GetIPAddress3(System.Net.Dns.GetHostName());
            ViewBag.ip6 = GetIP();
            ViewBag.ip7 = GetUserIP();
```

I have used multiple function it returns either the server`s ip address or the public ip address which is same for all the users. It doesn`t return the actual ip address that the user system has.

Comment: Its supposed to be that way, internal IP addresses are exactly that.  Whether you use 10.x, 172.x or 192.x as you cant route to it, or use it in any way, the only address is the public one.

Comment: Even if you do get the user's internal IP address, it won't be unique. The whole point of routers converting IP addresses is to allow multiple networks to reuse the same range internally.

Comment: The only thing the server can see is the public ip address of the last NATing router or proxy that passed the traffic. *FORWARDED_FOR headers can be faked; do not rely on them

Comment: Why do you think you need to do this? There is probably a better way to achieve your business requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I did it.

this is the solution:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
        // NOTE: window.RTCPeerConnection is "not a constructor" in FF22/23
        var RTCPeerConnection = /*window.RTCPeerConnection ||*/ window.webkitRTCPeerConnection || window.mozRTCPeerConnection;

        if (RTCPeerConnection) (function () {
            var rtc = new RTCPeerConnection({ iceServers: [] });
            console.log(rtc);
            if (1 || window.mozRTCPeerConnection) {      // FF [and now Chrome!] needs a channel/stream to proceed
                rtc.createDataChannel('', { reliable: false });
            };

            rtc.onicecandidate = function (evt) {
                // convert the candidate to SDP so we can run it through our general parser
                // see https://twitter.com/lancestout/status/525796175425720320 for details
                if (evt.candidate) grepSDP("a=" + evt.candidate.candidate);
            };
            rtc.createOffer(function (offerDesc) {
                grepSDP(offerDesc.sdp);
                rtc.setLocalDescription(offerDesc);
            }, function (e) { console.warn("offer failed", e); });


            var addrs = Object.create(null);
            addrs["0.0.0.0"] = false;
            function updateDisplay(newAddr) {
                if (newAddr in addrs) return;
                else addrs[newAddr] = true;
                var displayAddrs = Object.keys(addrs).filter(function (k) { return addrs[k]; });
                if (displayAddrs[0] === null || displayAddrs[0] === '') {
                    $('#txtIpAddress').val(displayAddrs.join(" or perhaps "));
                } else {
                    $('#txtIpAddress').val(displayAddrs[0]);
                }
                //$('#txtIpAddress').val(displayAddrs.join(" or perhaps "));
                //   console.log(displayAddrs[0]);
                //  alert(displayAddrs.join(" or perhaps "));
                // document.getElementById('list').textContent = displayAddrs.join(" or perhaps ") || "n/a";
            }

            function grepSDP(sdp) {
                var hosts = [];
                sdp.split('\r\n').forEach(function (line) { // c.f. http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4566#page-39
                    if (~line.indexOf("a=candidate")) {     // http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4566#section-5.13
                        var parts = line.split(' '),        // http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5245#section-15.1
                            addr = parts[4],
                            type = parts[7];
                        if (type === 'host') updateDisplay(addr);
                    } else if (~line.indexOf("c=")) {       // http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4566#section-5.7
                        var parts = line.split(' '),
                            addr = parts[2];
                        updateDisplay(addr);
                    }
                });
            }
        })();


    });
```